# Going through a JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I've got a JSONArray that I pull from a server, it is a report of the emails I send to the server. My goal is to go through it, pick the one with a specific subject and print the "recieved" number from that element of the array. The JSON looks like this:

```
[
{"rejections":58,"timestamp":"2014-08-08 12:46:26","subject":"2014/08/08 12:46:03.604: apitest ACTION_100_","clicks":0,"opens":28,"streams":0,"received":86,"bounces":0,"complaints":0,"unsubs":0}
{"rejections":77,"timestamp":"2014-08-11 13:54:49","subject":"2014/08/11 13:54:25.786: apitest ACTION_100_","clicks":0,"opens":14,"streams":0,"received":91,"bounces":0,"complaints":0,"unsubs":0}
]
```

I'm basically trying to echo the number associated with `"recieved":` where the subject is `"2014/08/11 13:54:25.786: apitest ACTION_100_"` ...  I don't know how to do the if statement. I know it will look something like:

```
if(thisElement["subject"].equals("2014/08/11 13:54:25.786: apitest ACTION_100_")){ 
    echo thisElement["recieved"]; 
}`
```

My code:

```
//json = the first code block in this post
//newSubj = the subject I mentioned above
JSONArray json = readJsonFromUrl(serverStats);
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
    //if(obj["subject"].equals(newSubj)) <----- ? 
    System.out.println(obj.toString()); // should this be obj["recieved"].toString()?
}
```

Comment: I think what you don't know how to do is compare Strings.

Comment: If you print obj.toString I *think* it should show you a JSON representation of the JSONObject.  (Can't keep track of all the different Java JSON kits.)

Comment: (Do you have a question??)

Comment: Hey, edited for string comparison. Yes printing obj.toString shows me the whole json object - i don't know how to look in that json object to check the value of subject, or to check the value of recieved. I'm using org.json

Comment: I know that this sounds rash, but did you consider actually looking at the documentation??

Comment: That doesn't sound any more rash than any of your other comments - And of course I have, I just didn't understand. It's a lot to look at in such a weird format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
if (newSubj.equals(obj.get("subject")) {
    int received = obj.getInt("received");
    System.out.println(received);
}
```